# How many 1080p Monitors i can connect to MacBook pro 13 inch 2019 model with 4 thunderbolt port?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

Can anyone please help me to connect my MacBook pro 13 inches with 4 thunderbolts to 3 external monitors ( one U2414H and two P2419H) ?

I tried connecting them using three type-c to HDMI convertors but I can only power any two of them with or without my built-in MacBook pro display.

any help would be appreciated, guys

my mac info:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at **Video Support** in: [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP795)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 13" MacBook Pro 2019 supports 2 external monitors (in addition to the built-in monitor).

If you want to connect more monitors, you'll external equipment such as a DisplayLink adapter or an eGPU for hooking up extra monitors.

Comment: do u if I can connect 2 external display using MST( daisy-chaining ) and another one using normal type-c to hdmi hub ?

Comment: macOS does not support MST, so unless you’re running Windows in BootCamp or similar, then no. You will need an eGPU or a DisplayLink adapter (could be in the form factor of a dock also).

Comment: @ jksoegaard , Will it works if I use two of the traditional type-c to HDMI connector to connect two monitors and use another display link adapter to connect third monitor? or do i have to connect all three monitors to DisplayLink adapter?

Comment: That’s fine - no need to have three.

Comment: just to confirm.  u mean I just need to use one DisplayLink adapter for just third monitor right?

Comment: Yes. But consider what you want to use the monitor for before buying - if you want to game for example, you’ll definitely want an eGPU and not DisplayLink.

Comment: no am just gonna use it to do some work stuff. no need for an eGPU,  also its kinda hard to find a good DisplayLink adapter. been searching for a while and found dell d6000, but getting very mixed reviews some say it's not working as expected with mac. some says it does. am kinda confused.